# Does iOS collects Pedometer(Step Counter) sensors data by itself or app needs to start the sensors to start collecting data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, healthkit, core-motion

I am working on a pedometer app. I have the following queries. Any help is welcome.

First:
**Does iOS collects Pedometer(Step Counter) sensors  data by itself ?** I don't want to start the sensor for motion activity from my app. I just want that as soon as the user launches the app for the first time, the app can query the  CMPedometer of CoreMotion Framework and get the data of last 5 days if Sensors had collected it.

Second:
User suspends(kill) the app. Does the motion sensors of iOS will still collect the data? If yes, as soon as the user starts the app again, app query for the data from a particular date in past using CMPedometer and the CMPedometer fetch all the data recorded during the app was in foreground/background/suspended state and then I can start live updates.

How much is the possibility?

Comment: Yes, step counting is always running. you can query data for any time period.

Comment: Thanks John. Yes it collects, I found it

Comment: Another question is, does the motion sensor writes to health store of Health Kit always, as I am using the HealthKit in my app. I don't want that the user needs to query the Core Motion library for background updates or launch the Health app to get updates in my app in which I am using Health Kit.

Comment: They don't need to run the Health app, the data will be there.

Comment: Okay Thank you @johnelemans